# Facing latency issues for Get calls while ingesting the data into elastic search

Tags: database, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-elasticsearch

I have one usecase where I dump the files in S3 and send notificaion to SQS. From SQS, I trigger lambda which reads the data from S3 buckets and writes the data into elastic search. Now problem I face when there is high ingestion rate in elastic search. During this time, my search latency increases alot. From my side, I have tried to take the following steps:

1. Limitdown number of records which we are writing in one batch (50 records in one batch)
2. Limit on number of concurrent (+ reserved) lambda instances
3. Upgraded my ES machines to 4 child nodes (c4.xlarge) and 3 master nodes

I don't want to scale up my ES as we do data ingestion twice a week.

I am looking for suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: What does writing 50 records in one batch mean? Are you dumping 50 files into S3 at a time? And does the Lambda receive and process one s3 object as input or it processes a batch of files at once?

Comment: @SarthakJain - We receive around 1000 files in S3 and in eash S3 file almost 40K records. 
For those 40K records we get the data for elastic search and compare it with S3 data to check the updated record. 
Now further from the filtered data we extract 50 records and write it into ES.